# Batch converting straight quotes to smart quotes from MySQL database

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2, quotes, smart-quotes

I have a MySQL table with about 250 blog entries, all using straight quotes (" and ') instead of smart quotes (“ ” and ‘ ’). I need to take those entries and somehow do a batch find-and-replace to replace all straight quotes with smart quotes. Problem is these fields also contain HTML, so I need to ensure all quotes within `<>` tags are ignored.

I've exported the appropriate fields and opened up in Sublime Text thinking I could do regex find-and-replace. It's there that I hit a wall, though.

Suggestions?

Comment: Any certain language?

Comment: @hwnd sublime text has its own regex find and replace. It uses http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to enter the smart quotes in Sublime Text 2, but I tested the following regex (in Sublime Text 2 itself) for the single quote case using `[]` as the replacement characters:

```
Find what:    ((?:[^<'>]*|<.*?>)*)'(.*?)'
Replace with: $1[$2]
```

Hopefully this will help.

Here is [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/8jQtZnK26P) for it, showing matches.

Comment: This still matches tags that are like `<a href="www.foo.com">` as OP states he wants to ignore all quotes within `<>`

Comment: @hwnd The first capture group is _intended_ to capture anything within `<>`, because those things remain. This regex only replaces the quotes, as the OP intended.

Comment: OP states `Problem is these fields also contain HTML, so I need to ensure all quotes within <> tags are ignored.`

Comment: And they are ignored, by the `<.*?>` expression, which is part of the original capture group and retained.

Comment: See updated edit with rubular (actually did it originally, just forgot to include it.

Comment: Oops, I up-voted the wrong comment, sorry. I actually tried to test this on Rubular but it gave me "Sad" error message...I guess it didn't like the regex :(

Comment: @cbmtrx Just tested this in rubular again and it worked. The rubular link in the answer was wrong, however, so I updated it. Have you tried the rubular link I provided?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I didn't end up needing this code but I did go back and try the rubular example again. It only works with the preset test text. When I try something like `this 'is a test to "see if” it will strip out pesky ‘symbols!'` it gives me this error: "Rubular suspects this regex will take forever to parse. Regexes of this sort make Rubular sad. Adjust the regex or else wait a few minutes and try again."

Comment: FWIW I'm using this in PHP to check incoming POST data and make any replacements of straight double quotes pairs with their smart quotes counterparts: `$cleanData = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"/', '&#8220;$1&#8221;', $_POST[$data]);` The same could be done for single quotes. (Of course, this is all parsed BEFORE it goes into the mySQL dbase.)

Comment: @cbmtrx Very strange. Didn't get any error when I tried that same text. See https://img42.com/L1vSB

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Strange indeed--this time it worked where twice before it wouldn't. Then I tried a few other tests and it started failing again. I think it's their UI, not your regex.